# Calculate Sum() but excluding JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

In the `sales` table, there is a `point` field. I want to `sum(point)` when grouping by `sales.submit_date` but that wont add up correctly because it will duplicate the records from `JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT sales.sales_id) as TotalSales, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT sales_lines.id) as TotalLiness
FROM `sales` 
    JOIN sales_lines ON sales_lines.sales_id = sales.sales_id
GROUP BY sales.submit_date
```

SQL above, this will count the number of sales in the `sales` table and also count number of lines in the `sales_lines` (number of lines matched to `sales_lines.sales_id = sales.sales_id`). This seem to work fine.

How do I sum(`sales.point') in the sales only?

Comment: Can you show tha table structure and some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could aggregate sales_lines up to the sales grain.

```
SELECT
  S.submit.date,
  ,sum(s.point)
  ,COUNT(s.sales_id) as TotalSales
  ,SUM(SL.SalesLines) as TotalLines
FROM
 sales S
INNER JOIN 
(Select
  sales_id
  ,count(distinct id) as SalesLines
 FROM
   sales_lines
 GROUP BY
  sales_id) SL
ON S.sales_id = SL.sales_id3
GROUP BY
 s.submit_date
```

Comment: Thanks, you might have miss-understood my question but I need `sum(sales.point) ` - Get the total points in the sales tables only. There is a `point` field in the `sales` table

Comment: Added in summing `sales.point`  (unless I'm completely missing something).